# what does ./ publicPath in webpack do

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

i see that a webpack property in a react app that i currently working has the property

```
publicPath: {
 ./
}
```

What does that mean? I cant find a clue on internet to fully understand this

Comment: I don't have any react/webpack experience so I may be incorrect, but I imagine `publicPath` lists directories to search for static files in. So a request for `website.com/a/b/index.html` with a public path of `./public` would likely cause it to search for `index.html` at `./public/a/b/index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

It allows you to specify the base path for all the assets within your application.

Essentially, every file emitted to your output.path directory will be referenced from the output.publicPath location. This includes child chunks (created via code splitting) and any other assets (e.g. images, fonts, etc.) that are a part of your dependency graph.

More info [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/#root)